# Как получить цвет пикселя getpixel(), когда у тебя ошибка: TypeError: argument must be sequence of length 2

Tags: python, pillow, pil

Я пытаюсь найти цвет пикселя rgb, но получаю овер много разных ошибок. Вот код:

```
listss = [640, 154]
r, g, b = img.getpixel(listss)
```

При таком варианте я получаю эту ошибку:

```
TypeError: argument must be sequence of length 2.
```

Что мне делать? Как это исправить? Подскажите пожалуйста.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Не без помощи конечно, но я решил этот вопрос. Спасибо CrazyElf'ку. У меня было 3 переменных (r, g, b), но картинка шла в rgba, то есть нужна была еще 1 переменная (r, g, b, a). Вот эта несостыковочка и выдавала ошибку: TypeError: argument must be sequence of length 2. А делее у меня выдавалась эта ошибка: ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 3). Ее я решил конвертированием списка в кортеж с помощь tuple(). Вот и все:) Вот что вышло:

```
listss = [640, 154]
r, g, b, a = img.getpixel(tuple(listss))
```

Comment: Только насчёт ошибок и их решений у вас всё наоборот перепутано )

Comment: Ясно( но у меня была вроде бы такая последовательность

Comment: Ну хорошо, что решил) Спасибо)

Comment: `too many values to unpack (expected 3)` - это ошибка про то, что ожидалось 3 значения `r, g, b =`, а пришло значений **ещё больше**, т.е. 4. Эта ошибка лечится изменением на `r, g, b, a =`. Так что ошибки перепутаны местами. Ну ладно, главное в итоге всё получилось. Просто ответ должен быть полезным, а если у вас всё перепутано, то это не очень полезно для тех, кто будет ответ потом читать.

Answer (score 0):

Используйте не список, а кортеж (круглые скобки, а не квадратные):

```
xy = (640, 154)
r, g, b = img.getpixel(xy)
```

Comment: У меня в программе не получается использовать кортежи, потому что в них нельзя добавлять новые элементы, а мне этот функционал очень нужен.

Comment: Поэтому я использую списки, но я пытался делать, то что вы говорите. Указывая в ковычках (аргументах), следующее: "tuple(listss)" И мне выдавало ошибку: ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 3)

Comment: А, ну тогда вероятно у вас больше цветовых компонент, у вас не `RGB` картинка, а `RGBA`, попробуйте не присваивать `r, g, b = ` результат работы функции, а напечатать его. Вангую, что там будет 4 числа, а не 3. Тогда должно работать такое присваивание: `r, g, b, a = `

Comment: Спасибо, я решил вопрос. Прочитайте если хотите:)